# Void* function with a parameter

Tags: c++

For an application I'm trying to write I need to be able to write `GLEnable(GL_REPEAT)` in an `interface` (got this working). Once the user does that, the system should call the function with the correct parameter.

For this, I am using the following variable to get the correct function:

`std::map<std::string, void(*)(GLenum)> glEnableDisable;`

And storing data in it through:

```
glEnableDisable["glEnable"]  = glEnable;
glEnableDisable["glDisable"] = glDisable;
```

> (Note that the above gives a warning "'=' cannot convert from 'void (__stdcall *)(GLenum)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(GLenum)'")

Finally, the function is called through:

```
((void (*)(GLenum)) Main.glEnableDisable[SplittedUp[0]])(Parameter);
```

Now, I wonder what I'm doing wrong. I had this working fine without parameters, but I really need parameters for this.

Thanks in advance,

Joey

Comment: It was never really "working fine" without parameters.  You're just lucky you didn't get a crash due to using the wrong calling convention (`__stdcall` vs. `__cedcl`)

Comment: The __stdcall is from the warning given by Visual Studio. It isn't part of my code (I'm trying to call the glEnable function from OpenGL)

Comment: Ignore warnings to your own peril. You should have asked yourself (or stackoverflow) "what is `__stdcall`? what is `__cdecl`? why does VS warn me about stuff that isn't even in my code?" before even trying to run anything.

Comment: @JoeyvanGangelen That warning can be considered fatal.  If your program did actually compile, as soon as you run it, you would probably get the "ESP could not be saved..." error, and then would cause another SO as to what this error means.

Comment: Derp... My bad, it's quite late here.. It's an error, not a warning. the __stdcall* part comes from the OpenGL system. I assumed it was a standard call procedure, hence why I didn't ask. Didn't even know about __cdecl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
std::map<std::string, void(*)(GLenum)> glEnableDisable;
```

to this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void(GLenum)>> glEnableDisable;
```

and never worry about calling conventions again. An `std::function` is able to store any function or callable object, whatever its calling convention is.

Cast is not needed:

```
Main.glEnableDisable[SplittedUp[0]])(Parameter);
```

Comment: Thanks :) This makes void* functions so much easier o.o

Answer (score 0):

The question is "how the store in `std::map<std::string, void(*)(GLenum)>` a function pointer that accepts parameters"? If yes, then the answer is: That is not possible, because you declared a map with a fixed function pointer signature. And the signature in your code sais, that the stored function pointer does not accept any parameters.

If you want to store parameter, then you have two options:

1. A wrapper function that accesses the parameters not over the stack and call the specified function with the provided parameters.
2. Create a map for every function pointer signature you are using.

Hint: Be lucky that your program didn't crash due to the wrong calling convention. It is advisable to adapt the calling convention to `__cdecl`.

Comment: The functions that should be in the map all use a FunctionName(GLenum) signature (if I didn't misinterpret you). What map could I use to store that signature correctly? The map only contains 2 functions, glDisable and glEnable, although for neatness sake I'd rather not use an if statement to find out which one it is.

Comment: @JoeyvanGangelen: Unfortunatelly it not possible. A container (e.g. std::map) accepts only the specified signature. With every parameter and it's data type the signature changes. If you want to make it generic, you have no other choice option 1. Another solution is a worker thread that reads ab command enum and an generic data structure that holds every parameter. In a switch/case block, u can identify the command and extract the parameters to pass it to the function. No elegant solution I know, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously:

```
void(*)(GLenum)
```

is *not* the correct prototype for the `GLenum` function.

This assumes a `C` calling convention, which in Visual Studio defaults to `__cdecl`.  However the actual function you want to call uses a different calling convention, namely `__stdcall`.

Something like this should solve the issue:

```
typedef void (__stdcall *GLenumFunc)(int, int); // or whatever your params are
//...
std::map<std::string, GLenumFunc> glEnableDisable;
```

As to what a calling convention is: [Calling Conventions on x86 platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)